# Docker nginx 404 issue

Tags: angular, docker, nginx

I have a SPA developed with Angular and i's like to deploy it within nginx using docker. When i tested, i always met 404 and dont know why, can somebody please help? Below is my configuration.

Docker nginx script:

```sh
set -e;
docker rm -f my-nginx;
docker run --name my-nginx -d -p 80:80 \
-v /Desktop/my-nginx/conf/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf \
-v /Desktop/my-nginx/log:/var/log/nginx \
-v /Desktop/my-nginx/html:/usr/share/nginx/html \
nginx
```

nginx.conf

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    server {
        listen      80;

        location ^~ /test {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /test/index.html; 
        }
       
    }
    
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

All files are deployed under test folder. It works fines when simply visit `http://localhost/test`, but throws 404 when i try to visit `http://localhost:test/myUrl`

The error message is `[error] 28#28: *10 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/test/myUrl" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.17.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /test/myUrl HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"`

Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;` from your nginx.conf as you are using a separate configuration file at `etc/nginx/nginx.conf` -- This will create conflicts.